# Property does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to use Typescript in my React app

In my `mapStateToProps` I have this code

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: AppState) => {
    console.log(state)
    return {
        ...state.player,
        position: state.player.position
    }
}
```

My AppState

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import playerReducer from './player';

export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  player: playerReducer
} as any);

export type AppState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>
```

And I'm getting an error `TypeScript error: Property 'player' does not exist on type '{}'.  TS2339` in relation to the line `...state.player`
But if I console.log state (on the line before that) My `state` has `player` property.

I'm not sure why am I getting this error. All the help will be appreciated.

**Player Reducer**

```
import { Action } from '../actions/types';
import { Store } from '../types';


export const initialState: Store = {
  position: [410, 0]
};


const playerReducer = (state = initialState, action: Action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'MOVE_PLAYER':
      return {
        ...state,
        position: action.payload
      }   
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default playerReducer;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `combineReducers` is unable to infer the type of the object that you're passing in due to `as any`. This means that your root reducer can only be inferred to by type:

```
const rootReducer: Reducer<{}, AnyAction>;
```

Simply take out the `as any` in `combineReducers`:

```
export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  player: playerReducer
});
```

Should be inferred as:

```
const rootReducer: Reducer<{
  player: PlayerState;
}, AnyAction>;
```

---

Try strong-typing your `playerReducer`:

```
import { Action, Reducer } from "redux";

const playerReducer: Reducer<Store, Action> = (state = initialState, a) => {
    ...
};
```

The *exact* pattern I use in my project would be something like this (of course, you may want to tweak it until you get something that works a bit better for your project):

```
import { Action, Reducer } from "redux";
import { MOVE_PLAYER } from "../actions/playerActions"; // list all relevant actions here

export interface PlayerState {
  readonly position: [number, number];
}

const initialState: PlayerState = {
  position: [410, 0];
};

const reducers: { [k: string]: (s: PlayerState, a: any) => PlayerState } = {
  [MOVE_PLAYER]: (s, a: { payload: [number, number] }) => ({ ...s, position: a.payload }),
  // other player reducers
}

const reducer: Reducer<PlayerState, Action> = (s = initialState, a) => {
  const f = reducers[a.type];
  return typeof f === "function" ? f(s, a) : s;
};
export default reducer;
```

Comment: Now I;m getting error at the line ```player: playerReducer``` The error ```TypeScript error: Type '(state: Store | undefined, action: ActionA) => Store | { position: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Reducer<Store | { position: string; }, AnyAction>'.
  Types of parameters 'state' and 'state' are incompatible.
    Type 'Store | { position: string; } | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Store | undefined'.
      Type '{ position: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Store'.
        Types of property 'position' are incompatible..```